# How did birds become so intelligent?

Tags: zoology, learning

I have seen a Discovery Channel video of a bird throwing stones in a pot to raise the water level so it is able to reach and drink it.

A similar experiment [in this paper from *Current Biology*](http://www.cell.com/current-biology/abstract/S0960-9822%2809%2901455-9) shows the same phenomenon under controlled conditions, and is documented in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7cw_9AT5hg).

This clearly illustrates how intelligent these animals are may well be more intelligent than many mammals. For example, the regular domestic dog will definitely not push stones in a bucket of water to quench his thirst.

How did crows, and perhaps birds in general, became so intelligent, and even more intelligent than many mammalian species?

Comment: Birds are animals and, as far as I know, there is no basis for your claim that they are the most intelligent.

Comment: @KlaytonThomas - I edited this question as well, but you should try to find an image, a link to a movie fragment or other source illustrating the claims you make on crows increasing water levels

Comment: Using a movie scene as an example is not an accurate form of asking a question. However, I have indeed seen documentaries detailing how intelligent crows are. I suggest you youtube it and find a suitable documentary clip.

Comment: @TheLastWord - I agree movie clips are not the best thing, but in this case I doubt there are scientific articles that support the claim

Comment: some one added "movie fragments" in my question not i, actually i seen this video in discovery channel.

Comment: I edited your question as I was expecting it to be put on hold. I voted to re-open as I like the question, but I am afraid it may be too vaguely defined. Give it a thought how to improve it and make it more approachable for folks here.

Comment: You should really define what you mean by intelligent... for instance a dog can bring you the newspaper, which a bird can't do.

Comment: The basic raise-the-water-level experiment described in this paper has been subsequently repeated and extended with a number of corvid species and also with human children; it is known as the [Aesop's Fable Paradigm](https://www.google.com/search?q=aesops+fable+paradigm).

Comment: @Corvus Yet another apropos name :P